# Mongoose schema infinite nesting

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having some trouble creating a model that describes the object that I want to store in mongoDB.

This is the object:

```
simple: [
    {
      label: 'Satisfied customers',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Good food',
          children: [
            { label: 'Quality ingredients' },
            { label: 'Good recipe' }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'Good service (disabled node)',
          children: [
            { label: 'Prompt attention' },
            { label: 'Professional waiter' }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'Pleasant surroundings',
          children: [
            { label: 'Happy atmosphere' },
            { label: 'Good table presentation' },
            { label: 'Pleasing decor' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This is data that is input to a QTree: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree

I want to model this but this object can in theory expand indefinitely as each child can have children of it's own and so on. Is there a way to do this nicely in a Mongoose Schema? My search so far turned up empty.

Here is what I have now:

```
simple: [{
  _id: false,
  label: String,
  children: [{
    _id: false,
    label: String,
  }]
}]
```

I can ofcourse choose to limit the depth to a certain amount (say 5) and put that amount of nesting in my schema, but I'm trying to find a more elegant solution so that I dont have to do that.

Comment: Mongo has some recommendations on how to implement tree structures. Refer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Comment: That is for mongoDB and I'm trying to make schema in Mongoose. I don't see how I can implement that in my situation.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am having this same issue as well

Comment: @ShawnVarughese No I did not, I did what I stated at the end of the post, I made a nested schema. You then of course have to take care of limiting the depth of your nesting when using the schema. I did not need infinite nesting, 5-10 was good enough.